# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am learning springboot and microservices.
I have created 3 services and all are working fine. Now i have created discovery server, using start.spring.io by adding "Eureka Server" as dependency.

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.springboot.microserices</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my main class is as follows:

```
    package io.springboot.microserices.discoveryserver;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableEurekaServer

public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

But i am unable to run the application. If i run, i am getting below exception. Could some one help me in resolving this issue.

```
16:07:02.761 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
```

Answer (score 6):

Finchley is not compatible with Spring Boot 1.x, You must use Boot 2.0.x. For Boot 2.1.x you need to use Greenwich.

Comment: Will Greenwich is compatible for spring boot 1.x?. Springboot 2.x is not working properly in my local. So i am using spring boot 1.x

Comment: It is not and will never be precisely because of incompatibilities like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the version mismatch issue. 
    It has nothing related with Eureka Spring Boot Code.
        To resolve the above problem. 
        Below is my working code. Refer the same.

Sample pom.xml code

```
       <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>Camden.SR6</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
```