# SpringBoot Application fails startup when adding dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, github-package-registry

I have an existing SpringBoot Application that was running with no issue. I then created a Java library—a standalone repository with only static Java code, no main class. My library is deployed as a GitHub Maven package.

I then proceeded with setting up my GitHub packages repository in my local Maven settings and added the dependency to my original SpringBoot application. The import process is successful, my library's Jar is in the classpath and compilation and build are successful.

What happens next is I run the application now, and I get the following stacktrace:

```
02:36:51.110 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [<redacted list of classpath dependencies, including my new library>]
02:36:51.223 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at my.org.transfer.TransferServicesApiApplication.main(TransferServicesApiApplication.java:18)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure what else to try and a night of Googling lead me nowhere.
This is my application's `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>appname</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- my library import -->
            <groupId>my.org</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-booter</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>formatter</goalPrefix>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My library's `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>Github Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/my-org/library-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.793</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>20.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks much.

---

Edit: set `spring-boot-starter-parent` version in application pom to match the version in the library pom. No changes.

---

Edit 2: This is the output of `mvn dependency:tree` (my library-injected dependency at the bottom):

```
[INFO] my.org.hopscotchtrading:transfer-services-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.16.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.38:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.38:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.12:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:19.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-logger-api:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.influxdb:influxdb-java:jar:2.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.moshi:moshi:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.msgpack:msgpack-core:jar:0.8.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:jar:3.14.9:compile
[INFO] \- my.org:mylibrary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:jar:1.11.793:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.793:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.793:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.10:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.147 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-19T13:06:54-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Also, note that you don't need to specify the ``spring-web`` dependency separately. The spring-boot-starter-web pulls that dependency for you. Also, you don't need to define the versions for lombok, commons-codec, commons-lang3. They are resolved by Spring Boot for you. The advantage is when you upgrade your Spring Boot dependency, those dependencies will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using different versions of spring-boot-starter-parent (2.3.1.RELEASE and 2.3.4.RELEASE) which is probably leading to inconsistent versions where the later or earlier don't have the method.  Try using 2.3.4.RELEASE in your application.

[Update]

You're still getting inconsistent versions of `org.springframework:*` on the classpath:

```
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.7.RELEASE:compile
```

In your application pom.xml remove the explicit dependency from

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and any other dependency that is specified in the parent so you get all 5.2.9 versions in the dependency output.

Finally, there is discussion like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498624/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-boot-builder-springapplicationb) about requiring specific versions for Spring Boot and the latest version of `spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config` is `2.2.4.RELEASE` which makes me think your library's POM needs to be updated to use the latest.

Comment: I'm sorry -- I suggest you try running `mvn dependency:tree` in your project to see if you can get a clue where there might be a version conflict.

Comment: Added output to question -- too long for comment.

Comment: I had *just* chagned the `spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config` version a moment before reading your update. That made the application bootstrap go slightly further but failed to initialized beans with `spring-web` dependencies. Removed that version as you suggested and worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!